# Compare dictionary content with Object

Tags: python, object, dictionary

I have the following object

```
class LidarPropertiesField(object):
    osversion = ''
    lidarname = ''
    lat = 0.0
    longit = 0.0
    alt = 0.0
    pitch = 0.0
    yaw = 0.0
    roll = 0.0
    home_el = 0.0
    home_az = 0.0
    gps = 0
    vad = 0
    ppi = 0
    rhi = 0
    flex_traj = 0
    focuse = 0
    type = 0
    range_no = 0
    hard_target = 0
    dbid = 0
```

Also I have a dictionary with the same fields, is it possible to compare the object fields with the dictionary fields in a for loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the `dict` is called `d`, this will check if `LidarPropertiesField` has the same values as `d` for all keys in `d`:

```
for k, v in d.iteritems():
     if getattr(LidarPropertiesField, k) != v:
         # difference found; note, an exception will be raised
         # if LidarPropertiesField has no attribute k
```

Alternatively, you can convert the class to a `dict` with something like

```
dict((k, v) for k, v in LidarPropertiesField.__dict__.iteritems()
            if not k.startswith('_'))
```

and compare with `==`.

Note the skipping over all class attributes that start with `_` to avoid `__doc__`, `__dict__`, `__module__` and `__weakref__`.

Comment: For better result if not isCallable(v) can be added. Found in operator module.

Comment: you don't necessarily want to compare the object's methods... or you might.

Comment: @Obtuse: well, the class has no methods. Besides, there's a builtin `callable` for that purpose (no idea why they duplicated it as `operator.isCallable`, but it is marked deprecated since Python 2.0).

Comment: @larsman Just explaining what I think RomanSusi was getting at.  IE... it might be nice if you are say comparing a serialized version of an object to it's python "equivalent", you might want to ignore comparing certain types to determine "equality".  Really, just depends on what iUngi really wants to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the built-in function [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr)

```
class Foo:
    bark = 0.0
    woof = 1.0

foo = Foo()

foo_dict = dict(bark = 1.0, woof = 1.0)
for k in foo_dict.keys():
    print 'Checking', k
    print getattr(foo, k)
    print foo_dict[k]
    if foo_dict[k] == getattr(foo, k):
        print '  matches'
    else:
        print '  no match'
```

Gives result:

```
Checking woof
1.0
1.0
  matches
Checking bark
0.0
1.0
  no match
```

Comment: This way some attributes can be left out (if they aren't keys in foo_dict) and the result of comparison will not be valid.